# FutureBuilder does not complete when using an Anmiation inside

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-future

I have a FutureBuilder, where I retrieve data from Firestore. I do that in initState, as it was often suggested here.

```
Future<Tour> _tour;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tour = _tourService.getTourDataPerEmployee(employeeID: userinfo.user.uid);
  }
```

My FutureBuilder looks like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: _tour,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data.waypoints);
            return Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.waypoints.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return TimelineTile(
                  nodePosition: 0.03,
                  contents: TourTile(
                    tour: snapshot.data,
                    index: index,
                  ),
                  node: TimelineNode(
                    indicator: CustomIndicator(
                        finished: snapshot.data.waypoints[index].finished),
                    startConnector: CustomConnector(
                        finished: snapshot.data.waypoints[index].finished,
                        inProgress: false),
                    endConnector: CustomConnector(
                        finished: snapshot.data.waypoints[index].finished,
                        inProgress: index >= snapshot.data.waypoints.length - 1
                            ? true
                            : snapshot.data.waypoints[index + 1].finished
                                ? false
                                : true),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ));
          } else {
            return Center(child: Text("Please wait"));
          }
        },
      ),
```

This is how I tried to add the animation:

```
CircularProgressIndicator()
```

This works fine, when I however try to replace the simple Text("Please wait") with an animation, I get weird results. I could get no result from the future at all, sometimes there are only a few results. The data simply does not seem to arrive sometimes, because the snapshot.data does print null sometimes, sometimes all results are there. I cannot see any coherences between the animation and the builder.

Comment: Might be helpful to share how you tried to implement the animation that caused the unexpected behavior. Also try `await` before `tourService` in your initState.

Comment: @Loren.A i have added details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Future<Tour> _tour;
  
  getTours() async {
    return await _tourService.getTourDataPerEmployee(employeeID: userinfo.user.uid);

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tour = getTours();
  }
```

Then in Widget:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: _tour,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data.waypoints);
            return Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.waypoints.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return TimelineTile(
                  nodePosition: 0.03,
                  contents: TourTile(
                    tour: snapshot.data,
                    index: index,
                  ),
                  node: TimelineNode(
                    indicator: CustomIndicator(
                        finished: snapshot.data.waypoints[index].finished),
                    startConnector: CustomConnector(
                        finished: snapshot.data.waypoints[index].finished,
                        inProgress: false),
                    endConnector: CustomConnector(
                        finished: snapshot.data.waypoints[index].finished,
                        inProgress: index >= snapshot.data.waypoints.length - 1
                            ? true
                            : snapshot.data.waypoints[index + 1].finished
                                ? false
                                : true),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ));
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
```

you can even call getTours() in future

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: getTours(),
```

Comment: works like a charm! I just had to add Future<Tour> in front of the getTours function and it worked!

Comment: yeah, forgot about that :)